# Json values into PHP event calendar if not soldout

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, compare

I have been stuck for days trying to figure out the best method to go about doing what I need done. I have a json url that I am pulling data from that is in an array like below. The date range can be a month to a full years worth of data. I need to do a check if tickets are `soldout` or not. If `soldout` equals true it should display `soldout` on that date in the calendar. If `soldout` equals false it should display the `$url` variable in the date in the calendar that matches the date in `start`.

Array format I am trying to work with

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (4) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "165"  
        ["start"]=> string(18) "05/02/2020 1:00 PM" 
        ["title"]=> string(19) "Event 1:00 PM" 
        ["alldetails"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) {  
                ["soldout"]=> bool(false) 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "166" 
        ["start"]=> string(18) "07/19/2020 5:00 PM"  
        ["title"]=> string(19) "Event 5:00 PM" 
        ["alldetails"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { 
                ["soldout"]=> bool(false) 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (4) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "167" 
        ["start"]=> string(18) "11/14/2020 9:00 PM" 
        ["title"]=> string(19) "Event 1:00 PM" 
        ["alldetails"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { 
                ["soldout"]=> bool(false)
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Pulling data from json array

```
<?php
$array = 'https://URL/feed.json?start=2020-05-02&end=2020-11-14';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($array));
foreach ($obj as $key => $value){
    $id = $value->id;
    $start = $value->start;
    $title = $value->title;
    $url = '<a href="https://url/'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    $details = $value->alldetails;
    foreach($details as $nested){
        $nested->soldout; //Outputs 1 or is blank
    }
}
?>
```

Someone else's calendar I have been attempting to insert data into. Not sure if I should use this or try my hand at building my own. Not very good with date formatting in PHP Long way to learn and a lot of refreshers needed.

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
<th><strong>M</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>W</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>F</strong></th>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";    
    else echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So to break it down once again, I need to insert `$url` into the calendar where `start` date matches the calendars correct date but only if not `soldout`. If `soldout` equals true then it should probably just `echo "SoldOut";` or leave blank, something to that nature. Any help getting on the right track to get the information in the calendar would be great.

Comment: Are both your php snippets in one file? Meaning you have the decoded json available in the script building the calendar table?

Comment: Both snippets are all in one file, Can not use 2 different files as I am trying to implement it into Wordpress using a php plugin, I do not have access to backend files in wordpress so have to use the plugin to add code to pages.

Comment: Ok, so while iterating to build your calendar cells, you just need to check that date against the decoded json. Checking will also be a simple iteration where you compare your current date against the dates in the record and when found, return either the link or the string "sold out".

Comment: Yes that is where I am having my issues lol

Comment: So can you show the function you tried to make that achieves this so we can identify where the problem is?

Comment: I cant as I tried many things and kept switching things up. I do not know where to start when building a function to achieve this due to the way the calendars variables are, If it was a single variable for the calendar it would make things much easier on me. I am stuck trying to get a compare due to the way the calendar is written. Still learning things.

Comment: I was given this function as an example but got very confused with it.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd64972d2d4ec2593256ede62330f446ac0aa19f

Comment: I agree with the current close vote -- this question is Too Broad, Needs Focus, could be achieved in too many ways , and even borders on opinion-based.  Please do more development and isolate your point of failure.  A bounty is not for paying people more unicorn points so that you can put forth less effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped a great deal by @El_Vanja, Taught me a great deal about creating a function that would do exactly what I was looking for. Seems I was going about things the wrong way and he guided me to find the correct answer helping along the way as much as he could while still teaching me to do it myself. Kudos to @Il_Vanja, would make a great PHP teacher.

Here is the working code, Still needs cleaned up a great bit including the if statements for displaying the events but as is it works as expected.

```
<?php
$array = 'https://feed.json?start=2020-01-01&end=2100-12-31';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($array,true));
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"><div class="m_buttons"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" ><strong>Previous Month</strong></a></div></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><div class="m_buttons"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" ><strong>Next Month</strong></a></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>Sun</strong></th>
<th><strong>Mon</strong></th>
<th><strong>Tues</strong></th>
<th><strong>Wed</strong></th>
<th><strong>Thurs</strong></th>
<th><strong>Fri</strong></th>
<th><strong>Sat</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
function getDateCellContent(array $obj, $d) {
    $f_newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j', $d);
    $f_newdate = $f_newdate->format('m/d/Y');
    $cellLink = '';
    $cellSoldout = '';
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        $start = $value->start;
        $a_newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:i A', $start);
        $a_date = $a_newdate->format('m/d/Y');
        $a_time = $a_newdate->format('g:i A');
        $id = $value->id;
        $title = $value->title;
        if($a_date === $f_newdate) {
            foreach ($value->alldetails as $details) {
                $name = $details->name;
                $title = $value->title;
                $link1 = '<div class="link1"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link2 = '<div class="link2"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link3 = '<div class="link3"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link4 = '<div class="link4"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link5 = '<div class="link5"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link6 = '<div class="link6"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link7 = '<div class="link7"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link8 = '<div class="link8"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link9 = '<div class="link9"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link10 = '<div class="link10"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                $link11 = '<div class="link11"><a href="./setup/'.$id.'" target="_blank"><strong>'.$name.'<br />'.$a_time.'</strong></a></div>';
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Event 1:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link1;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Event 10:00 AM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link2;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Event 2:30 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link3;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Mother's Day Event 1:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link4;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Sunset Event 6:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link5;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Spring Event 10:00 AM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link6;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "All Day Event 10:00 AM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link7;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Winter Event 3:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link8;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Winter Event 5:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link9;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Winter Event 7:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link10;
                }
                if (!$details->soldout && $title === "Father's Day Event 1:00 PM") {
                    $cellLink .=  $link11;
                }else{
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $cellLink . $cellSoldout;
}
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";    
    else echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>".($i - $startday + 1) ."<br />". getDateCellContent($obj, $cYear.'-'.$cMonth.'-'.($i - $startday + 1)) ."</td>";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go and let me know if it's what you want.

I've created an array that holds all the events for the specified date range. Then, when the calendar is being populated, it checks if the current day is in the array. If so, it displays whether it's available or sold out.

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left" onclick="changeDate(<?php echo $prev_month .','. $prev_year; ?>);" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right" onclick="changeDate(<?php echo $next_month .','. $next_year; ?>);" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
<th><strong>M</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>W</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>F</strong></th>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];

$eventsArray = array();

$array = 'https://URL/feed.json?start='.$cYear.'-'.$cMonth.'-'.$startday.'&end='.$cYear.'-'.$cMonth.'-'.$maxday;
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($array));
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value->id;
    $start = $value->start;
    $title = $value->title;
    $url = '<a href="https://url/'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    $details = $value->alldetails;
    $date = new DateTime($value->start);
    $day = $date->format('d');
    foreach($details as $nested){
        $soldOut = $nested->soldout;
        array_push($eventsArray, array($day, $soldOut));
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    $currentDay = $i - $startday + 1;
    if($i % 7 == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    if($i < $startday) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }else{
        // Check if current day is in array $currentEvents
        foreach($eventsArray as $event){
            if($event[0] == $currentDay) {
                if($event[1] == 1) { // event is soldout
                    echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><p>".$currentDay."</p><p>Soldout</p></td>";
                }else{
                   echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><p>".$currentDay."</p><p>Available</p></td>"; 
                }
            }else{
                echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><p>".$currentDay."</p><p>No Event</p></td>"; 
            }
        }
    }
    if($i % 7 == 6) {
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Already got the answer I was looking for I just forgot to post it for others. Ill give you the bounty anyway just to be done with it and for your effort. :P, BTW I do not want to create a new JSON array as I already have one I am pulling from somewhere. Looks like you are creating a new one here. From this it looks as if I would be pulling the data from itself instead of from the correct source.